# SQL change column datatype in production

Tags: sql-server

I need to alter some columns from nText to Nvarchar(max) on a active database with a simple query like

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] nvarchar(max);
```

But my question is, would this be safe to do on database in production? The tables differs from 50 rows to 2m rows. And to answer that question, I think my question should be:

**What is the SQL-server doing under the hood when you change a Ntext datatype column to a Nvarchar(max)?**

I have tried to find reading material on this, but without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a table rebuild because of how they are stored internally.
However, 2 million rows is not too bad so it make only take a few minutes

I would consider doing it differently though to allow batching and ensure all data is converted OK.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] ADD [ColumnTemp] nvarchar(max);
GO
UPDATE [dbo].[Table] SET ColumnTemp = Column
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] DROP COLUMN Column
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Table.ColumnTemp', 'Column', 'COLUMN'
GO
```